# Why does my array list alwas has a size of one?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to read polynomials from a list, from the main method and pass them as an objects to an array list in the Polynomial.class. There I should split them and create a linked list of Nodes contain monomials so later I can do math operations to the polynomials. 
I managed to read the polynomials from the file and pass them to the array list in the constructor of the Polynomial class, however; the array list in the constructor shows size of 1, that makes it impossible (for my level of knowledge) to split them into monomials and create linked chain of nodes.

This is for a college project.

```java
    //the mail class
    public class MainClass {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Polynomial poly;
        ArrayList <Polynomial> polyList = new ArrayList<> ();
        String str;


            try {
            File inputFile = new File ("polynomial.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner (inputFile);
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                str = scanner.nextLine();
                 poly = new Polynomial(str);
                 polyList.add(poly);
            }  
            scanner.close();  
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File not found!!");
          }//end of catch 
       }
    }

     //here is the Polynomial class
    import java.util.ArrayList;

      public class Polynomial {

      public Polynomial (String poly) {

        ArrayList<String> polyList = new ArrayList<>(); 
        polyList.add(poly);

        System.out.println(polyList.size()); 

    }
```

Here is the actual input:

```
    2x^2+4x+5
    7x^2+12
    4x^2+7x+6
```

I'm getting an arrayList polyList size of one, but I have all t he elements from the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring new ArrayList in constructor. So each time it will create a new arraylist and add that value into current array list. So list size will be always want. I guess instead of printing the size into the Polynomial class, you may print it in main class: for example:

```
   public class MainClass {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Polynomial poly;
    ArrayList <Polynomial> polyList = new ArrayList<> ();
    String str;


        try {
        File inputFile = new File ("polynomial.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (inputFile);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
             str = scanner.nextLine();
             poly = new Polynomial(str);
             polyList.add(poly);
        }  
        scanner.close();
        // ################## Print it here ###########  
        // Actual size 
        // ###########################################
        System.out.println(polyList.size()); 


    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File not found!!");
      }//end of catch 
   }
}
```

Also learn how to debug java using IDE(eclips/netbeans/IDEA).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I realized my mistake. Here is the correct code:

```
    //the mail class
public class MainClass {   
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Polynomial poly;
    ArrayList <Polynomial> polyList = new ArrayList<> ();
    String str;


        try {
        File inputFile = new File ("polynomial.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (inputFile);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            str = scanner.nextLine();
             poly = new Polynomial(str);
             polyList.add(poly);
        }  
        scanner.close();  
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File not found!!");
      }//end of catch 
   }
}

 //here is the Polynomial class
import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class Polynomial {

  public Polynomial (String poly) {

      String [] monomial;
      monomial = poly.split("[+]");
      for (int i = 0; i < monomial.length; i++)
      System.out.println(monomial[i]);


}
```